# CSS grid is overflowing

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a CSS grid.
This is my HTML code:

```
<div  id="updates" class ="wrapper">
    <div id="content">
        <section id="services" class="last clear">
          <ul>
            <li>
              <article class="clear">
                <figure><img src="images/demo/180x150.gif" alt="">
                  <figcaption>
                    <h2>Indonectetus facilis leo nibh</h2>
                    <p>content content content <a href="#" title="Free Website Templates">link to other content</a>. For full terms of use of this template please read our <a href="https://www.os-templates.com/template-terms">website template licence</a>.</p>
                    <footer class="more"><a href="#">Read More &raquo;</a></footer>
                  </figcaption>
                </figure>
              </article>
            </li>

          </ul>
        </section>
      </div>
   
    
    <div id="content">
        <section id="services" class="last clear">
            <ul>
            <li>
                <article class="clear">
                <figure><img src="images/demo/180x150.gif" alt="">
                    <figcaption>
                    <h2>Indonectetus facilis leo nibh</h2>
                    <p>content content content <a href="#" title="Free Website Templates">link to other content</a>. For full terms of use of this template please read our <a href="https://www.os-templates.com/template-terms">website template licence</a>.</p>
                    <footer class="more"><a href="#">Read More &raquo;</a></footer>
                    </figcaption>
                </figure>
                </article>
        </li>

        </ul>
    </section>
</div>
```

My CSS file looks like this:

```
.wrapper{
    height: 90vh;
    margin: 2rem;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
    /* grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr ; */
    /* margin-top: 5%; */
    /* margin-left: 15%; */

}

.wrapper > div {
    padding:1em;
}

.updates, .updates a{color:#C0BAB6; background-color:#333333;}

#header, #updates, #footer{display:block; width:600px; margin:0 auto;}
body{margin:0; padding:0; font-size:13px; font-family:Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif; color:#afaeae; background-color:#232323;}

address, article, aside, figcaption, figure, footer, header, nav, section{display:block; margin:0; padding:0;}
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6{margin:0; padding:0; font-size:16px; font-weight:bold; font-style:normal; line-height:normal; text-transform:uppercase;}


.clear:after{content:"."; display:block; height:0; clear:both; visibility:hidden; line-height:0;}
.clear{display:block; clear:both;}


img{margin:0; padding:0; border:none; line-height:normal; vertical-align:middle;}
.imgholder, .imgl, .imgr{padding:4px; border:1px solid #D6D6D6; text-align:center;}
.imgl{float:left; margin:0 15px 15px 0; clear:left;}
.imgr{float:right; margin:0 0 15px 15px; clear:right;}
#updates #content #services{}
#updates #content #services ul{margin:0; padding:0; list-style:none;}
#updates #content #services ul li{display:block; width:100%; margin-bottom:30px;}
#updates #content #services ul li.last{ margin-bottom:0;}
#updates #content #services ul li article{}
#container #content #services ul li article figure{}
#updates #content #services ul li article figure img{float:left; width:180px; height:150px; margin:0; padding:4px; 
    border:1px solid #666666;}
#updates #content .more{
    text-align:right;

}
```

This grid should be side by side. I did look at Firefox developer tab and it was saying overflow at `updates id`[image]

I don't seem to understand why the the entire `id=content` is centered? Which is likely to cause the the overflow. I don't see any left-margin or padding which is causing the content to centered.

It looks like this right now [image]

I used this:

```
  .wrapper > div {
        padding:1em;
    }
```

Do I need to target a specific class content for it to work? Because it seems like grid on all div.

Comment: I don't understand what's supposed to be the problem. Can you try to better describe what's the problem and what are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: @ŠimonSlabý Sure, on wrapper I described described 3 columns for the grid. But when the contents are being displayed stacked. I wanted to `id=content` to be displayed side by side.

Comment: Can you edit your question and add a snippet which illustrates the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your outermost element has both a class of `wrapper` and an id of `updates`. And then you’re applying multiple style rules either from the class or the id, and these are interfering with each other.

Your first style rule sets up your grid:

```
.wrapper {
  display: grid;
}
```

But then your fourth style rule tells it to be a block instead of a grid:

```
#header, #updates, #footer {
  display: block;
}
```

I suggest you need to split your fourth style rule into two rules as follows:

```
#header, #footer {
  display: block;
}
#header, #updates, #footer {
  width: 600px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Here is a snippet to demonstrate:

```css
.wrapper{
    height: 90vh;
    margin: 2rem;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
    /* grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr ; */
    /* margin-top: 5%; */
    /* margin-left: 15%; */

}

.wrapper > div {
    padding:1em;
}

.updates, .updates a {color:#C0BAB6; background-color:#333333;}

#header, #footer {display:block;}
#header, #updates, #footer{ width:600px; margin:0 auto;}
body{margin:0; padding:0; font-size:13px; font-family:Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif; color:#afaeae; background-color:#232323;}

address, article, aside, figcaption, figure, footer, header, nav, section{display:block; margin:0; padding:0;}
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6{margin:0; padding:0; font-size:16px; font-weight:bold; font-style:normal; line-height:normal; text-transform:uppercase;}


.clear:after{content:"."; display:block; height:0; clear:both; visibility:hidden; line-height:0;}
.clear{display:block; clear:both;}


img{margin:0; padding:0; border:none; line-height:normal; vertical-align:middle;}
.imgholder, .imgl, .imgr{padding:4px; border:1px solid #D6D6D6; text-align:center;}
.imgl{float:left; margin:0 15px 15px 0; clear:left;}
.imgr{float:right; margin:0 0 15px 15px; clear:right;}
#updates #content #services{}
#updates #content #services ul{margin:0; padding:0; list-style:none;}
#updates #content #services ul li{display:block; width:100%; margin-bottom:30px;}
#updates #content #services ul li.last{ margin-bottom:0;}
#updates #content #services ul li article{}
#container #content #services ul li article figure{}
#updates #content #services ul li article figure img{float:left; width:180px; height:150px; margin:0; padding:4px; 
    border:1px solid #666666;}
#updates #content .more{
    text-align:right;

}
```

```html
<div  id="updates" class ="wrapper">
    <div id="content">
        <section id="services" class="last clear">
          <ul>
            <li>
              <article class="clear">
                <figure><img src="https://i.guim.co.uk/img/media/88f6b98714035656cb18fb282507b60e82edb0d7/0_54_2560_1536/master/2560.jpg?width=465&quality=45&auto=format&fit=max&dpr=2&s=40d77868a83c41b1b8f969b6d83bc911" alt="">
                  <figcaption>
                    <h2>Indonectetus facilis leo nibh</h2>
                    <p>content content content <a href="#" title="Free Website Templates">link to other content</a>. For full terms of use of this template please read our <a href="https://www.os-templates.com/template-terms">website template licence</a>.</p>
                    <footer class="more"><a href="#">Read More &raquo;</a></footer>
                  </figcaption>
                </figure>
              </article>
            </li>

          </ul>
        </section>
      </div>
   
    
    <div id="content">
        <section id="services" class="last clear">
            <ul>
            <li>
                <article class="clear">
                <figure><img src="https://i.guim.co.uk/img/media/88f6b98714035656cb18fb282507b60e82edb0d7/0_54_2560_1536/master/2560.jpg?width=465&quality=45&auto=format&fit=max&dpr=2&s=40d77868a83c41b1b8f969b6d83bc911" alt="">
                    <figcaption>
                    <h2>Indonectetus facilis leo nibh</h2>
                    <p>content content content <a href="#" title="Free Website Templates">link to other content</a>. For full terms of use of this template please read our <a href="https://www.os-templates.com/template-terms">website template licence</a>.</p>
                    <footer class="more"><a href="#">Read More &raquo;</a></footer>
                    </figcaption>
                </figure>
                </article>
        </li>

        </ul>
    </section>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Your `.wrapper` class is overriding by `#updates`, because **id** has higher priority than **class**.

```css
#header,
/* #updates, */ /* remove this ID */
#footer {
  display: block;
  width: 600px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

###### 1) If you don't care about how many columns you need

```css
.wrapper {
  height: 90vh;
  margin: 2rem;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(360px, 1fr)); /* changed */
}
```

###### 2) If you need only 3 columns

```css
.wrapper {
  height: 90vh;
  margin: 2rem;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, minmax(360px, 1fr)); /* changed */
  grid-auto-rows: auto; /* new line */
}
/* added breakpoint */
@media screen and (max-width: 1200px) {
  .wrapper {
    grid-template-columns: minmax(360px, 1fr);
  }
}
```

```css
.wrapper {
  height: 90vh;
  margin: 2rem;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(360px, 1fr));
  /* grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr ; */
  /* margin-top: 5%; */
  /* margin-left: 15%; */
}

.wrapper>div {
  padding: 1em;
}

.updates,
.updates a {
  color: #c0bab6;
  background-color: #333333;
}

#header,
/* #updates, */
#footer {
  display: block;
  width: 600px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-family: Georgia, 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
  color: #afaeae;
  background-color: #232323;
}

address,
article,
aside,
figcaption,
figure,
footer,
header,
nav,
section {
  display: block;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6 {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-style: normal;
  line-height: normal;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.clear:after {
  content: '.';
  display: block;
  height: 0;
  clear: both;
  visibility: hidden;
  line-height: 0;
}

.clear {
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}

img {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: none;
  line-height: normal;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.imgholder,
.imgl,
.imgr {
  padding: 4px;
  border: 1px solid #d6d6d6;
  text-align: center;
}

.imgl {
  float: left;
  margin: 0 15px 15px 0;
  clear: left;
}

.imgr {
  float: right;
  margin: 0 0 15px 15px;
  clear: right;
}

#updates #content #services {}

#updates #content #services ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

#updates #content #services ul li {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

#updates #content #services ul li.last {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

#updates #content #services ul li article {}

#container #content #services ul li article figure {}

#updates #content #services ul li article figure img {
  float: left;
  width: 180px;
  height: 150px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 4px;
  border: 1px solid #666666;
}

#updates #content .more {
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<div id="updates" class="wrapper">
  <div id="content">
    <section id="services" class="last clear">
      <ul>
        <li>
          <article class="clear">
            <figure>
              <img src="images/demo/180x150.gif" alt="" />
              <figcaption>
                <h2>Indonectetus facilis leo nibh</h2>
                <p>
                  content content content
                  <a href="#" title="Free Website Templates">link to other content</a>. For full terms of use of this template please read our
                  <a href="https://www.os-templates.com/template-terms">website template licence</a
                      >.
                    </p>
                    <footer class="more"><a href="#">Read More &raquo;</a></footer>
              </figcaption>
            </figure>
          </article>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </section>
  </div>

  <div id="content">
    <section id="services" class="last clear">
      <ul>
        <li>
          <article class="clear">
            <figure>
              <img src="images/demo/180x150.gif" alt="" />
              <figcaption>
                <h2>Indonectetus facilis leo nibh</h2>
                <p>
                  content content content
                  <a href="#" title="Free Website Templates">link to other content</a>. For full terms of use of this template please read our
                  <a href="https://www.os-templates.com/template-terms">website template licence</a
                      >.
                    </p>
                    <footer class="more"><a href="#">Read More &raquo;</a></footer>
              </figcaption>
            </figure>
          </article>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </section>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The text should be on its side though not bottom

Comment: I'm not sure exactly whitch grid you want and added two instances. First is flexible, the second one only has 3 columns. Snippet has been updated.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a way how to display each article next to each other in a row I would suggest using Flexbox for creating the layout.

In this case, you can add display flex to you class `wrapper` in CSS:

```
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}
```